# Rasterizing multiple shapes into integer-labeled 3D numpy arrays for a python based addon

Tags: python, mesh, modifiers, geometry-nodes, remesh

I would like to convert multiple blender mesh objects into label-based python/numpy arrays.

For example, I have two intersecting shapes - 1) a cylinder "C", 2) a sphere "S", see attached image. In a Python addon I am working on, I want to rasterize this scene into a 3D integer numpy array, where each enclosed region is uniquely labeled, for example,

- the region enclosed by C excluding S (C-S),is labeled as 1
- the region enclosed by S excluding C (S-C),is labeled as 2
- the region enclosed by "C and S" (C&S)),is labeled as 3

[image]

I don't know if there is such a function to rasterize shapes in blender. the closest I could find in Blender is the **Remesh modifier** with the "Block" option. Choosing this option converts the shapes, including intersecting surfaces, into voxel-like squared patches. By looping these patches, I can potentially rasterize the surface into a shell of boundary voxels, then with some floodfill algorithms, I may be able to fill the enclosed voxels into unique labels.

However, I found that the remesh modifier does not respect the "water-tight" nature of the surfaces. From the above screenshot, you can see there are small gaps between the voxelated cylinder and sphere surfaces. I don't know how to remove those.

I am open to any suggestion how to achieve this goal using Blender or Python (via `bpy`). I assume this can be done via geometry node programs?

Comment: Computing all possible intersections for arbitrary shapes (or even arbitrary manifolds) will be very difficult, I think, but if the shapes are somewhat simple (e.g. convex or not too non-convex), you can probably use something like `BHVTree.ray_cast` (https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.bvhtree.html#module-mathutils.bvhtree) in a few dozen directions to get reasonable detection of what objects have a boundary close to a given point, and to determine whether you're inside/outside the interior of each object, then build your indexing assignment logic using this as a subroutine

Comment: I am not sure if your comment "computing all possible intersection" was to address the gaps that I found in the remeshed surfaces, but blender was perfectly capable of handling intersections of complex objects and we have been successfully able to use it for our mesh-based model (see our paper: https://doi.org/10.1117/1.JBO.27.8.083014). However, the non-watertight issue is only a problem when using the remesh modifier. Again, I am not limit myself to the remesh modifier, but open to any other approaches to rasterize multiple intersecting objects.

Comment: No, it wasn't about water-tightness; the problem you described wanting to solve (assigning a unique label to each distinct enclosed space) doesn't seem to me to require voxelization. I think it can be achieved by using raycasts to classify appropriately chosen points as inside/outside each original (non-voxelized) 3D object. What I meant about difficulty is that more sample points and larger numbers of raycasts will be needed the more important it is to capture portions of an object with very high curvature.

Comment: So, for example, I imagine you could do this: 1. determine a bounding box that contains all your objects 2. for every pair of points in a 3D grid, check if a raycast from A to B crosses 0 surfaces; if so, these two points lie in the same enclosed space. And that's the entire thing, I suppose; there is extra information you can extract from the raycasts, and lots of ways you can make it more efficient (e.g., a first pass should raycast from each point by itself to identify and remove from use grid points that never intersect any of the objects), but this is the basic idea

Comment: And my comment about difficulty, in this approach, translates to needing the number of grid points to be something like proportional to the reciprocal of the largest rate of change you want to be detectable in the objects' surface---i.e., if there is a very small 'bump' of an object just barely intersecting another object, the grid has to be chosen to be fine enough to capture this detail, if it matters. (I don't think this needs a large number of raycast *directions*, though, contrary to what I wrote originally; use of a 3D grid of sample points removes the need for that)

Comment: I haven't thought about it deeply, but you may be able to iterate over the vertices of all objects and use something like the smallest distance between two vertices for all objects in a particular region of space to adaptively choose the number of sample points in that part of the space. Some form of this idea could remove the need for pre-specifying a grid that is sufficiently precise, by instead defining the sample points so that there are more of them exactly in those regions where some of the objects' surfaces change very quickly

Comment: @NeverConvex, my goal is not to simply assign shape regions by unique numbers, but doing so in a voxelated array. I can already solve this by calling `bpy`->`oct2py`->Octave/MATLAB and call my matlab based surface razterization function [surf2vol.m](https://github.com/fangq/iso2mesh/blob/master/surf2vol.m). But it is somewhat slow. There are a few other ways this can be solved in MATLAB/Octave. However, I want to use Blender's rich features and solve this more efficiently. The methods you described seems to be even more computationally expensive & less robust than my existing MATLAB solutions.

Comment: Hm--maybe. I haven't read your paper, so not sure what your algorithm's run-time is like. I think you could make the approach I described above pretty efficient by limiting the raycasts to sample points that are near vertices of the objects; there's no reason to use sample points that are far from all objects' surfaces, now that I think about it.

Anyway, that may be all the help I can give; the only other option in Blender that occurs to me is to use binary operators to find intersections/unions of objects, but I expect this would be error-prone, and am not sure if it would be efficient.